# OpenFrameworks setting for latest xcode_How can I make a new project?

Tags: xcode, openframeworks, setting

I started OpenFrameworks for fun :D

However, setting OF in Xcode is little bit confusing.

According to web search, just copy and paste Example and edit that project.

It is little bit uncomfortable since workspace location is restricted.

Now I am curious is there any tutorial which start with xcode - [new project]?(I mean xcode UI)

So I can make OF Xcode workspace anywhere I wanted.

A Link can be very granted.

Thanks for answer:D

PS. If you do not mind please attach answer as answer section, not in reply, so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you mean with workspace location is restricted, do you mean that the location where you can put your project is limited?

Generally all projects in openframeworks are being put inside the apps folder of openFrameworks. Technically it is possible to take a project out, but it's not recommended.

You can both have a structure like this:

```
openframeworks/apps/myApps/myNewSuperOfApp
```

or

```
openframeworks/apps/someProject/myNewSuperOfApp
```

Copying the example is one way of creating a new project, but a easier way (sometimes) is to use the project generator that you find in projectGenerator_osx

You do not want to create an empty project in xcode and, then add openframeworks to it. The projects that are generated with the project generator (or the examples) have a lot of settings that are needed in the xcode project for them to compile with openframeworks. It's not something that you easily can add to an empty xcode project.

Comment: Yeap. I got your point. I guess it is mostly like setting Visual Studio with third party libraries. I know it is very hard and annoying work. But I want to do this in that way, so I can understand xcode and openframeworks more.(I think if I could understand those settings very well, I could user other third party libraries in same way. so I can use any of them, even if they do not provide specific guidelines).

Comment: It's up to you, but just so you are warned, it's very complex, and not something i've heard anybody doing besides the people who created the templates. It's a myriad of build settings that needs to be correct, and the only way you can do that is by looking in a project that compiles and copy the settings. I'm not sure what you would learn from that :) The build system behind openframeworks is very complex, because it supports a lot of platforms with the same build files.